# Mi Yodeya Questions and answers, men and women

Tags: talmud-gemara, women, stackexchange

I learnt (I don't remember source) that a main reason women don't learn Gemora is to prevent intergender conversing. I wonder if discussing on Mi Yodeya contravenes this mandate.

Comment: AFAIK all our users are women.

Comment: In general, if you don't know if a mandate exists, it's better to find out before asking about an application it.

Comment: I hear you. I don't really think in sequential order.

Comment: I'm unsure as to where you heard this. My aunt, aleha hashalom attended a cheder in pre-war Hungary and learned Gemara, there. What would make learning Gemarah more prohibitive than learning Chumash or anything else? Rabbi Binyamin Kamenetzki told me that his original yeshiva that he set up in Brooklyn was mixed gender.

Comment: did you ask him if all the classes were together? Some school will stream the girls to do something else during Gemora

Comment: Mrs R Geller, a belated welcome to Mi Yodeya. Maybe you will be interested by something I wrote to help you understand the site ["A beginner’s guide to MY - How is this site different from other Judaism sites”](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)
 ? I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: thank you to you and all the others who gave me such a warm welcome here.

Comment: @MrsRGeller I welcome you too (you seem like a smart lady I might learn a lot from you)

Comment: AFAIK There's no prohibition to learn Gemara. The Gemara (ha) in Kiddushin 30a just says there's no commandment to learn Torah *in general*. No mention is made of specifically Gemara.

Comment: @DoubleAA I know for sure they are not all men or all women

Answer (score -1):

In my understanding (this is a very controversial topic now due to the rise of the feminist movement) the prohibition on leaning Gemara (any Torah that is not practical) was because
1 because most woman do not have an obligation to be altruistic (see rambam below) so there knowledge of the gemoro (and any Torah that is not practical) will make it harder for them to control their yetser harah (since now they will know the loop holes how (ie what to say) not to get punished).
2 because it is harder for them to show respect for its logic

But woman need to lean the laws pertaining to them

Shulchan aruch harav talmud torah
[1.14](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/14.htm)

> ...ואף על פי שיש לה שכר צוו חכמים שלא ילמד אדם את בתו תורה מפני שרוב הנשים אין דעתן מכוונת להתלמד ומוציאות **דברי תורה לדברי הבאי** לפי עניות דעתן ואם מלמדה תורה שבעל פה הרי זה כאלו מלמדה תפלות מפני **שעל ידי זה נכנס בה ערמומית**...

[Mishneh Torah » Sefer Madda » Teshuvah
Teshuvah - Chapter Ten](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911914/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-Ten.htm)

Halacha 1

> A person should not say: "I will fulfill the mitzvot of the Torah and occupy myself in its wisdom in order to receive all the blessings which are contained within it or in order to merit the life of the world to come."
>
> "[Similarly,] I will separate myself from all the sins which the Torah warned against so that I will be saved from all the curses contained in the Torah or so that [my soul] will not be cut off from the life of the world to come."
>
> It is not fitting to serve God in this manner. A person whose service is motivated by these factors is considered one who serves out of fear. He is not on the level of the prophets or of the wise.
>
> The only ones who serve, God in this manner are common people, **women**, and minors. They are trained to serve God out of fear until their knowledge increases and they serve out of love.

Halacha 5

> Anyone who occupies himself with the Torah in order to receive reward or in order to protect himself from retribution is considered as one who is not occupied for the God's sake.
>
> [In contrast,] anyone who occupies himself with it, not because of fear, nor to receive a reward, but rather because of his love for the Lord of the entire earth who commanded it, is one who occupies himself for God's sake.
>
> Nevertheless, our Sages declared: A person should always occupy himself with the Torah even when it is not for God's sake for out of [service which is not intended] for God's sake will come service that is intended for God's sake.
>
> Therefore, when one teaches children, **women**, and most of the common people, one should teach them to serve out of fear and in order to receive a reward. As their knowledge grows and their wisdom increases, this secret should be revealed to them [slowly,] bit by bit. They should become accustomed to this concept gradually until they grasp it and know it and begin serving [God] out of love.

See http://m.jpost.com/Magazine/Judaism/May-women-study-the-Talmud

I did not see anywhere that it is to prevent conversing

But if it is

**I wonder if discussing on Mi Yodeya contravenes this mandate**

Reasons Why not.
1 it is not like conversing in person (no seeing or hearing),
2 and for sure not like conversing in private,
3 conversing itself is not forbidden if it is for a reason

PS the problem of conversing is for the man (not the woman) (as by the law of an unmarried teacher) that the boy does not have a wife and when he sees a woman he might get aroused and he does not have an ability to calm himself

Shulchan aruch harav Talmud Torah
[1 13](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/13.htm)

> ...מי שאין לו אשה או שאשתו בעיר אחרת לא ילמד תינוקות מפני שאמותיהם מביאות את בניהם לבית הספר ויתגרה בו יצרו מה שאין כן כשאשתו עמו בעיר יש לו פת בסלו אם יבא לו הרהור ויתקפנו יצרו שלא יוכל להסיח דעתו יוכל לבא אל אשתו.
>
> ויש מתירין למי שיש לו אשה אפילו היא בעיר אחרת ולכן אין למחות ביד המקילים

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39743/discussion-on-answer-by-hazoriz-mi-yodeya-questions-and-answers-men-and-women).